# How do I have a user enter values between 1 and 5, where 1 will return the employee information saved in the list index [0] in python

Tags: list

I am completely new to Python and am at a standstill because I don't know where to go from here. Here is what I have come up with so far in this problem.  I am creating a list via user input that will display several items.  I believe that I have created the proper list but I can't figure out how to pull elements from the list by having the user input a number 1-5 that is associated with the index from the list.

I hope that I am explaining this properly, but I am lost!!  Any help will thoroughly be appreciated!

employee_info = [ ]

for i in range(0, 5):

```
employee_index = [input('Employee Name\n'), input('Employee SSN\n'), input('Employee Telephone Number\n'), input('Employee Email\n'), input('Employe Salary\n')] 

employee_info.append(employee_index)

print(str(input("Select a number, 1-5, that will display the employee's information.")))
```

UPDATE:  I WAS ABLE TO FIGURE IT OUT. I USED IF/ELIF TO ASSOCIATE THE INDEX TO A VALUE ENTERED BY THE USER.
[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqr6x.jpg)

Comment: arrays start from 0 so if the user inputs number X, access the array at index X-1. Just have to make sure X-1 isn't greater than the total elements in the array

Comment: Hi thanks for the help!  Ok, that makes sense that the list index starts at 0 and in this case, employee_info[0].  I don't quite understand the rest of your comment though.  Is there a way to assign employee_info[0] to '1' so that when the user inputs '1', in the final line of code, it will actually display the value of employee_info[0]?  I hope that I'm not being too confusing cause I feel like I just confused myself.  SMH.

Comment: When a user inputs "1" you want to take that value and subtract one from it, and then access the array with that value. Maybe I can write an answer

Comment: Hi guys.  Thanks for your help.  Your input helped me to figure out a new option. I was able to figure it out.  I updated it above.